# Vanishing window content (blank/white/black) using Unity with Nvidia graphics card

Tags: 11.04, unity, nvidia

After about an hour ubuntu starts to behave strangely:

[image: screenshot]

A lot of resizing (vertically, but sometimes horizontally) redraws contents, but this is very annoying.

Is there a way to fix it?

> Graphic card: 00:05.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation C51 [GeForce Go 6100] (rev a2)

I'm using nvidia-current drivers (270.41.06-0ubuntu1).

Comment: What application(s) is/are doing that?

Comment: It happens to all applications (Banshee, google chrome, nautilus).

Comment: That is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/753144

Workaround: install 173 version of nvidia driver.

Answer (score 3):

@Sayane actually answered this question but in a comment not an answer so I'm just repeating what he said, @Sayane takes all credit for this answer:

That is a known bug: [bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/753144](http://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/753144) Workaround: install 173 version of nvidia driver.